# Laravel: Let user select MODEL and then get query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel project, which should be somewhat modular.

I have written a search query and what I want is following:

**Models:**
Assessment A
Assessment B
Assessment C

**View:**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'search')) }}

<select multiple name="search_by_form[]">
 <option selected>Any</option>
 <option value="assessment_a">A</option>
 <option value="assessment_b">B</option>
 <option value="assessment_c">C</option>
               
</select>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Controller:** 
The controller is much more complex but I made it easier for you to understand what my need is.

Now something like follows:

```
$user_entry =$request->input('search_by_form', []);
$resultArray = [];
foreach ($user_entry as $entry){
  if ($entry == "assessment_a"){
      $model_results = AssessmentA::where("approved",1)->get();
  
  } elseif ($entry == "assessment_b"){
      $model_results = AssessmentB::where("approved",1)->get();
  } elseif($entry == "assessment_c"){
      $model_results = AssessmentC::where("approved",1)->get();
  }
}
```

What I want:

SearchViewController:
foreach through Models in specific folder

then:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'search')) }}

<select multiple name="search_by_form[]">
  
 <option selected>Any</option> 
 @foreach($models as $model)
 <option value="{{ $model }}">{{ $model->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Instead of having such an ugly approach is it possible to have more something like this:

```
foreach ($user_entry as $entry){

   $entry::where("approved",1)->get(); #Obviously the values on the view would be change to "AssessmentA", etc.

}
```

I this feasible?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will create any array like this:

```
$model_array = ['assessment_a' => AssessmentA::class];
```

Then in loop simply pass value

```
foreach ($user_entry as $entry){

   $model_array[$entry]::where("approved",1)->get(); #Obviously the values on the view would be change to "AssessmentA", etc.

}
```

Comment: But then it would mean that I need to manually add this to the code. So if I would add a new Assessment: AssessmentD. I need to add this to the array but I want it to have "automated". But thanks for you input!

Comment: @Piroo you will need to define what are valid values at some point, otherwise a user could pass an invalid value and you would be trying to access a class that doesn't exist (you have to constrain what values you will accept from the data for these Models)

Comment: @lagbox Yeah you are right thanks! I totally forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: @Piroo if this answer is helpful please mark it done and close the thread

Answer (score 0):

If you change the select values to the actual table names, you could do it easily

```xml
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'search')) }}
<select multiple name="search_by_form[]">
 <option selected>Any</option>
 <option value="assessments_a">A</option>
 <option value="assessments_b">B</option>
 <option value="assessments_c">C</option>
</select>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

```php
$user_entry = $request->input('search_by_form', []);

if (empty($user_entry)) {
    model_results = collect();
} else {
    $query = DB::table(array_shift($user_entry))->where('approved', 1);

    foreach ($user_entry as $table) {
        $query->union(fn($union) => $union->from($table)->where('approved', 1));
    }

    $model_results = $query->get();    
}
```

Comment: I will try that out. But I am wondering if there is a Eloquent way to reach this?

Comment: Grouping all assignment tables in a sql view with an added column like "type" filled with values like assignment_a, b, c, etc. Then making a model for that view and just querying it `AssignmentView::whereIn('type', $user_entry)->get();`